# Why is CMake ignoring assembly files when building static library?

Tags: assembly, cmake, static-libraries

I've set

```
set(CAN_USE_ASSEMBLER TRUE)
```

And it's not helping at all. I'm trying to create a static library with a command like:

```
add_library(${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME} STATIC
            ../PropWare ../spi ../spi_as.S ../sd)
```

where the files without extensions are C++ or C files and the .S file is assembly. But when I run cmake and make, it compiles the C/C++ sources and just ignores the assembly file... no warnings, no errors... just skips right over it.

I'd love any ideas. Full source is available on [github](https://github.com/SwimDude0614/PropWare/tree/cmake) (do note: this link is to the cmake branch, all others should be ignored). The first line is in [this file](https://github.com/SwimDude0614/PropWare/blob/cmake/PropellerToolchain.cmake) and the second line is in [this file](https://github.com/SwimDude0614/PropWare/blob/cmake/PropWare/cmm/CMakeLists.txt).

Comment: Cmake still does this a decade later. You tell it about some asm source, it silently ignores it, until you stumble across this post in confusion and raise a PR adding the line 'project'. Thank you for the question - without it I'd have never found this in their docs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that you can enable `ASM` in the [`project()` command](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/project.html#command:project) too. For example:

```
project(abc
        LANGUAGES C CXX ASM)
```

Comment: This is really the _right_ answer to the question :) Not sure why I never came back and updated it lol

Answer (score 13):

### Update

See this better answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/67902603/2784641
It's not always possible to know what languages you need enabled at the time that the `project()` command is invoked... but probably 99.9% of the time it is, so go with this route. If, however, you need to programmatically enable different languages, based on some configure-time logic, then my original answer will work for you.

### Original Answer

Finally found it. Instead of

```
set(CAN_USE_ASSEMBLER TRUE)
```

I should have used

```
enable_language(ASM)
```

Answer (score 1):

When using gcc, you can compile `.S` files with your C compiler (no explicit invocation of asm needed). CMake can be told to do so using

```
set_property(SOURCE <myfile>.S PROPERTY LANGUAGE C)
```

for each of your `.S` files. Then they got compiled in...

Comment: I suppose that is an option that would work. But why not just enable assembly via the `enable_language(ASM)` command?

Comment: And actually, I do have CMake set to use `gcc` instead of `as` for building assembly files.

Comment: I actually had to use this technique with the language set to `ASM_NASM` so cmake would include my files. Otherwise, it would just ignore the nasm altogether.