# How to add dependecy to built-in assembly file target in cmake

Tags: assembly, cmake, dependencies

For every source file CMake automatically creates targets for preprocessor and assembly files generation, e.g. for file `foo.cpp` there will be `foo.s` and `foo.i` targets.
I would like to use the existing `.s` target and add it as a dependency for another target which will use to process that assembly file.
I tried a couple of tricks but none of them worked. When I tried to access the output file location property for the assembly target CMake complained with an error that such target might not exist.

For instance with:

```
add_library( parse
    src/parse.cpp
)
get_property( parse_asm TARGET src/parse.s PROPERTY LOCATION )
```

I get

```
CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:40 (get_property):
  get_property could not find TARGET src/parse.s.  Perhaps it has not yet
  been created.
```

but `make help` lists amongs others:

```
... src/parse.o
... src/parse.i
... src/parse.s
```

Comment: CMake commands operate with **CMake targets**. There is no target `src/parse.s` in your script. that is why CMake complains. *Targets for `make`* are different things. You may try to deduce path to `.s` file from path to resulted library file. As for dependencies, it is unlikely that dependency from `.s` file will work. Instead, you may create dependency from whole *library target* (`parse` in you case).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is CMake ignoring assembly files when building static library?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23452089/why-is-cmake-ignoring-assembly-files-when-building-static-library)